# How to check the checkbox after receiving the message in android

Tags: android, sms

I am making an application for android mobiles in which i have to receive the message string and then split that string in parts(each parts containing 2 characters).I am able to do up-to this much.
And after this now i have to check the checkbox depending on the string.
For ex-if my String is a1a2a3
then i have splited into a1, a2 & a3.Now i have a screen of 5 vertical check boxes.where 1st box represent a1,2nd one a2 and so on the 5th one representing a5.
Now after receieving the message(a1a2a3) i want that when i open the checkbox page then i should get the first three checkboxes to be checked.

On testing with debugger attached i found that i am able to receive the message and also i am able to split the message string but i am not able to apply check on the checkboxes.

Plz help me out.its very urgent.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
    CheckBox checkBox;
    if(A.a1==1){
        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.Checkbox_a1);
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
```

Whats the rocket science in this? Have u added the tag:

```
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
```